# Search fails to find code terms

Tags: support, search, search-box

Here's an answer of mine that I sometimes want to reference (when answering another question, or marking another question as a duplicate):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815177/341994

What I remember about it is that I said `viewDidLoad` was too soon. So I search on my answers that include "viewDidLoad", "too", and "soon":

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A341994+viewDidLoad+too+soon

The desired answer does not appear among the search results. I take it that this is because code terms such as `viewDidLoad` are excluded as matches. I suggest that that's a bug.

Comment: If it is code, search in code: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3AviewDidLoad&mixed=1

Comment: @rene This is sounding good. How do I combine that with my original search? I still want just the words "viewDidLoad", "too", and "soon" in only my own answers.

Comment: @pnuts yeah that code: option is hidden somewhere in an MSE post

Comment: @pnuts Should we be asking for some sort of revision of the search interface to expose this sort of option? Can you formulate that as an enhancement request on Meta? I'm not very good at these things.

Comment: Searching code is not very reliable.  Consider giving yourself a distinctive user name to give Google a better shot at helping you.

Comment: @HansPassant "Searching code is not very reliable" would itself make a good Meta bug post. :)

Comment: Do you mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166487/7412986)? Google has [no problem finding it](https://www.google.com/search?q=viewdidload+"too+soon"+matt+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: Does everyone here secretly work for Google? My question is about Stack Overflow's search feature.

Comment: I can Bing if for you?

Comment: @pnuts support this FR on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146546/add-code-search-syntax-to-search-tips

Comment: @rene I've [added this](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/commit/4e6484253e7709262e85f12951af0cb2e91f0926) to my advanced search [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As `viewDidLoad`  is in code you need to apply the `code:` option to search, like so

> [`too soon code:viewDidLoad`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+too+soon+code%3AviewDidLoad&mixed=1)

it will return answers with *too* and *soon* in the normal body and `viewDidLoad` in code markup.

Strangely enough that `code` option isn't documented in the [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) but it is mentioned on MSE by Nick Craver [Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161785/158100)

Add `user:me` if you want to limit result to only your posts, add `is:a` if you're only interested in answers.

<sup>Please [support the feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146546/add-code-search-syntax-to-search-tips) to have that `code:` option added to the search tips and help pages.</sup>

Comment: Perfect-o-rama with a silk pyjama! The only remaining issue is that there's no way to know that, but that would be a different question. Thanks!

Comment: So useful that I've created a search template and made it a Safari bookmark. Thanks again.

Comment: Re *"... that code option isn't documented"*: It could be a candidate for *[What are the hidden features of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen done now. I guess you'll find it soon-ish and give it an active reading?

Comment: Oh thanks, we now have much more to clean up: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22enter+code+here%22